# Jenkins: Ivy build randomly triggering other projects

Tags: git, jenkins, ant, ivy

I am building a few Ivy projects (with several components each) that are in GitHub using Jenkins.

I have, let's say, Ivy projects A (with components a1, a2, a3), B (with components b1 and b2) and C (components c1, c2, c3, c4). Each component has its own `ivy.xml` file.

I created an Ivy job in Jenkins and I have a variable where I set the name of the GitHub project, and then the jobs clones the repository.

E.g., in the "GitHub project" field of the job I have: `https://mygithub.com/myorg/${project}`, while `project` is a job parameter that can be `A`, `B` or `C`.

When I trigger the job, let's say passing `${project} = A`, I expect components a1, a2 and a3 to be built. That does happen.

However, I also get the following lines at the end of the console output:

```
Warning: you have no plugins providing access control for builds, so falling back to legacy behavior of permitting any downstream builds to be triggered
Triggering a new build of Build_and_JUnit » Build-develop » myorg.projectB.b1
Triggering a new build of Build_and_JUnit » Build-develop » myorg.projectC.c1
Triggering a new build of Build_and_JUnit » Build-develop » myorg.projectC.c3
Triggering a new build of Build_and_JUnit » Build-develop » myorg.projectC.c4
Finished: SUCCESS
```

(ps.: these are just examples)

... and components b1, c1, c3 and c4 are built!

I have no idea why Jenkins is building other components since I only requested A to be built. These components aren't even dependencies of the components of A.

By the way, the set of components that are built is random - it is not even consistent. I assume it has something do to with the warning at the first line.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the job was the parameterized GitHub project name.

I replaced the configuration with DSL jobs using `Jenkinsfile` (Pipeline plug-in) and now I have one job for each project and the problem is gone.